# (Django) Can't understand why my Python classes inherit the wrong method

Tags: django, oop, inheritance, django-views

I created a parent class as such:

```
class ProjectCreateMixin(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectCreationForm
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProjectCreateMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

And then two sub classes that inherits from `ProjectCreateMixin`, as such:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class CreateProjectView(ProjectCreateMixin):
    template_name = 'projects/project_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        ProjectUser.objects.create(user=self.request.user, project=self.object, role='admin')
        return redirect("projects:list")


class ProjectWizardCreate(ProjectCreateMixin):
    template_name = 'wizard-project-create.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        ProjectUser.objects.create(user=self.request.user, project=self.object, role='admin')
        return redirect("timesheets:default-current-week")
```

When I'm calling the `ProjectWizardCreate` on a URL:

```
path("wizard/project", ProjectWizardCreate.as_view(), name="wizard-project"),
```

and successfully submits its form, why is it redirecting to `("projects:list")` and not to `("timesheets:default-current-week")`?

Comment: Are you sure that your `ProjectWizardCreate.form_valid(...)` method gets executed?

Comment: have you written the  get_absolute_url method in  the models.py for Project model?

Comment: Does your wizard template have the right endpoint `<form action="{% url 'projects:wizard-project' %}">`?

Comment: My god, of course - I totally forgot about the `action` in the form. That was the culprit - thanks for your help!
Is there a better way of making this work so I don't have to have two duplicate `form_valid` methods? The only thing I wish to change is the `success_url`